# I'm trying web scraping but getting a function and not the actual data

Tags: python, html, css

I'm new with python and web scraping. I guess it's quite simple, but I can't make it work.

I created a local web-page with flask that contains a table and a function that fills it.
The next step is to get this data in other computers. This is what I tried:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000')
soup = BeautifulSoup(source_code)
```

and this is what I get:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8"/>
<link href="https://www.w3schools.com/w3css/4/w3.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="w3-container w3-teal">
<h1>SpaceWire Devices</h1>
</div>
<div>
<table class="w3-table-all w3-large" id="device_table">
<colgroup>
<col/>
<col/>
<col/>
</colgroup>
<tr class="w3-blue">
<th>Device ID</th>
<th colspan="2">Channel 1 (Left)</th>
<th colspan="2">Channel 2 (Left)</th>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
<script>
        //first add an event listener for page load
        document.addEventListener( "DOMContentLoaded", get_json_data, false ); // get_json_data is the function name that will fire on page load

        //this function is in the event listener and will execute on page load
        function get_json_data(){
            // Relative URL of external json file
            var json_url = '/status';

            //Build the XMLHttpRequest (aka AJAX Request)
            xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
                if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {//when a good response is given do this

                    var data = JSON.parse(this.responseText); // convert the response to a json object
                    append_json(data);// pass the json object to the append_json function
                }
            }
            //set the request destination and type
            xmlhttp.open("get", json_url, true);
            //set required headers for the request
            // xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            // send the request
            xmlhttp.send(); // when the request completes it will execute the code in onreadystatechange section
        }

        //this function appends the json data to the table 'gable'
        function append_json(data){
            var table = document.getElementById('device_table');
            for (var device in data) {
                var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                tr.innerHTML = '<td>' + data[device].id + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[device].channel_1 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[device].channel_1_port + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[device].channel_2 + '</td>' +
                '<td>' + data[device].channel_2_port + '</td>'
                table.appendChild(tr);
            };
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

What I really want is the data that append_json() in the end creates. How I do it?

Comment: You should use Selenium for Javascript scraping

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Jammy Dodger's comment about selenium is correct. The html is generated by js. You're request doesn't allow that code to execute like it would in a browser. I would use selenium to open the page and then retrieve the DOM that way. From there you can navigate and scrape the data you want. It should look something like this.

```
  from selenium import webdriver
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.firefox_binary import FirefoxBinary
  from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

  options = Options()
  options.add_argument("--headless")
  binary = FirefoxBinary('/usr/lib/firefox/firefox')
  browser = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_options=options, firefox_binary=binary)
  url = f'https://www.rottentomatoes.com/search/?search={title}'
  try:
    browser.get(url)
    # Give the js a little bit of time to generate the html
    time.sleep(1)
    html = browser.page_source
    browser.quit()
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
```

Comment: thanks a lot. I had troubles with activating the firefox driver, so I used chromium instead but you have given me the answer

Comment: Glad to hear. Happy hacking!

Answer (score -1):

You should call soup.get_text() or you can get specific tag: soup.find("a") or even for i in soup.find_all("a"): i.get_text()